# LinkedIn Gem Ruby: OAuth (permission_unknown)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, linkedin-api

I am trying to use the LinkedIn gem to access LinkedIn. I can't seem to get past getting access.

My code is this:

```
@client = LinkedIn::Client.new(API_KEY, SECRET)
@rtoken = client.request_token.token
@rsecret = client.request_token.secret
puts "token: #{@rtoken} secret #{@rsecret}"
@authorize_url = client.request_token.authorize_url
puts "authorize url: #{@authorize_url}"
@pin = @authorize_url.split("oauth_token=").last.strip
puts "pin #{@pin}"
@keys = @client.authorize_from_request(@rtoken, @rsecret, @pin)
@client.authorize_from_access(@keys)
```

And that produces the error:

```
token: sdklghsdgksdghskdhg secret shdlgkshdgshsdk
authorize url: https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=sdkghskldghsdkg
pin fslkdghskdghdsgkhsdkhg
OAuth::Problem: permission_unknown
```

Not really sure where to start on this. I've tried to find what permission is missing, but I'm at a loss.

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I've just started playing with this myself. I hit this same issue unless I manually paste the authorize URL into my browser, and then click Accept to allowing the requested permissions to my account. Then a pin is printed on the screen which I enter in for the authorize_from_request call.

So this line in your code is incorrect - the last part of the URL is a generated_token as the [README](https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin#authenticate) indicates, not a pin. I'm not sure of a programmatic way to do this.

```
@pin = @authorize_url.split("oauth_token=").last.strip
```

Comment: No, I gave up on this for now.

Comment: This doesn't work for me though. I am able to get the pin and when doing `client.authorize_from_request(rtoken, rsecret, pin)` it says permissions_unknown :/

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue. It turns out request_token.authorize_url does not return the pin. It just gives you a URL to visit where you can authenticate and generate a pin. Then you'll have to copy the pin into your application. A more elegant solution is this:

```
puts request_token.authorize_url
puts "Access the URL above. Authenticate. Enter the PIN here:"
pin = gets.strip
access_keys = client.authorize_from_request(rtoken, rsecret, pin)
```

This prints the URL and directs the user to authenticate, then enter the pin into the application.